# Firestore Event Listener within Containers/Pods

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

I have a project that runs on containers in a pod. Each pod will listen to a document change in firestore, however I only want this listener to be triggered once after a document has been changed.

The problem is, that the event will be triggered multiple times - based on # of pods active.

What are some possible solutions to this issue?

Comment: persist the count in firestore.
`if the listener is running or already ran { dont run the listener. } else  run the listener and save the state.`

Comment: Okay, but the listener gets triggered across 2 pods at the same time. How does pod 1 know any information about pod 2? This solution wouldn't be feasible.